# Changing text on a button/label after a certain period of time in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

I wish to use it to change text on a button to that of another label after a certain period of time.

For **example**:

```
label1.text = "Stack Overflow"

//Wait 5 seconds

button1.setTitle( "\(label1.text!)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/457406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this extension on Double:

```
extension Double {
    private func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
    }
    // Delay function written by Matt on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift/24318861#24318861



    func waitSecondsAndDo (closure:()->()) {
        delay (self, closure: closure)
    }
}
```

And then you can use it in your code like this:

```
5.0.waitSecondsAndDo {
   button1.setTitle( "(label1.text!)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```